# Fix JSON structure using python

Tags: python, json

Can you advise on a list of actions/commands I need to do in order to fix the below JSON using Python.
Current:

```
{
   "artifacts":[ 
     [ 
         "path: scheduler-task",
         "version: 0.28.2",
         "type: helm",
         "chart: scheduler-task",
         "repository: amd-core-test-helm-release"
     ]
   ]
}
```

Expected:

```
{ 
   "artifacts":[ 
     {
         "path": "scheduler-task",
         "version": "0.28.2",
         "type": "helm",
         "chart": "scheduler-task",
         "repository": "amd-core-test-helm-release"
     }
   ]
}
```

Comment: what encoded the original string, i'm interested in the library that did that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is to remap each string "foo: bar" into a dictionary with key as "foo" and value "bar". The snippet below converts the data in the required format.

```py
import json

data = {
  "artifacts": [
    [
      "path: scheduler-task",
      "version: 0.28.2",
      "type: helm",
      "chart: scheduler-task",
      "repository: amd-core-test-helm-release"
    ],
    [
      "path: ordernotification-notifycustomer",
      "version: 0.29.5",
      "type: helm",
      "chart: ordernotification-notifycustomer",
      "repository: amd-core-test-helm-release"
    ]
  ]
}

for i in range(len(data["artifacts"])):
  item_dict = {}
  for item in data["artifacts"][i]:
    key, value = item.split(": ")
    item_dict[key] = value
  data["artifacts"][i] = item_dict

print(json.dumps(data))
```

Output:

```
{
  "artifacts": [
    {
      "path": "scheduler-task",
      "version": "0.28.2",
      "type": "helm",
      "chart": "scheduler-task",
      "repository": "amd-core-test-helm-release"
    },
    {
      "path": "ordernotification-notifycustomer",
      "version": "0.29.5",
      "type": "helm",
      "chart": "ordernotification-notifycustomer",
      "repository": "amd-core-test-helm-release"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to know what encoded his original string? I'm wondering what was used it for encoding, as there might be an easier way to decode it with a library. +1 great answer

Comment: you could use `split(": ")` with space to remove this space from value.

Comment: @oppressionslayer, indeed that'll be helpful. If OP provides the source, we can write a generalized routine for it or use some in-built function.

Comment: This would fail if the `item` has multiple `:`. `item.split(":", 1)` may be better. Hopefully, the values will never be nested though.

Comment: @Kirk, true that. This however solves the current problem, so can be left for the OP to figure out I guess.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Agreed! Just pointing it out upfront in case the OP's problem is a bit more complex than the example given.

Comment: how can I handle it in case of two items:
 { 
   "artifacts":[ 
      [ 
         "path: scheduler-task",
         "version: 0.28.2",
         "type: helm",
         "chart: scheduler-task",
         "repository: amd-core-test-helm-release"
      ],
      [ 
         "path: ordernotification-notifycustomer",
         "version: 0.29.5",
         "type: helm",
         "chart: ordernotification-notifycustomer",
         "repository: amd-core-test-helm-release"
      ]]}

Comment: @ShubhamSharma getting wrong json (all wrapped with apostrophe instaed of quotation marks: {'artifacts': [{'path': 'scheduler-task', 'version': '0.28.2', 'type': 'helm', 'chart': 'scheduler-task', 'repository': 'amd-core-test-helm-release'}, {'path': 'ordernotification-notifycustomer', 'version': '0.29.5', 'type': 'helm', 'chart': 'ordernotification-notifycustomer', 'repository': 'amd-core-test-helm-release'}]}

Comment: @arielma Python uses single quotes to print string wrappings. In essence, the variable was just a dictionary that we were printing. However, we can serialize it to a true JSON using the json library. Check my edit.